# gWaei Translator for Windows?

Tags: linux, windows-vista, translation

*Avoiding* a full Cygwin-like install, is there some equivalent to the **Japanese-English** translation/reference tool [gWaei](http://gwaei.sourceforge.net/) from Ubuntu/Gnome, but for **Windows**?

If not, what open source translators allow us to review and look up **both** English and Kanji characters?

Update: *My Gozoku test-drive was not good, because I discovered it doesn't take romaji input like gWaei seemlessly does (ie: you can't type the english characters for "arigato" and get a japanese dict lookup in Gozoku because it is a pure dictionary). Also, Gozoku answers a search with a result tree that isn't pastable without some expansion of branches, right-clicking and choosing "save to clipboard."*

*gWaei allows you to easily get a flat list of results where you don't HAVE to copy whole words. When you lack a Japanese keyboard layout or the knowlege to use one, cutting bits and pieces of different japanese results as if they were newspaper collages is great for putting together a google-able search is nice. I'll check out the sourceforge build of gWaei and see if I needn't look elsewhere.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been slowly working on Windows support in gWaei for the last year.  I did my latest build with Mingw32 at http://sourceforge.net/projects/gwaei/files/gwaei/3.0.2/.  It has been tested with Wine, but not a real Windows install, so any help or bug reports are appreciated.

The good:  Most of the features are working (in Wine at least)
The bad: Themes with gtk3 on Windows are still half baked so it is a bit ugly using the fallback look

I'm hoping when gtk+-3.1.x starts making its way around, I can fix the final blemishes.

Comment: Wow. It's great to see a dev who hasn't already been posting found this question. Thanks for the link! I'll take it for a test drive since I have a dual-boot. I'm also updating my question with Gozoku testing feedback.

Comment: I've installed it on two windows PCs and it works just as intended. I guess it had been a long time since I last installed it, because I forgot about its semi-automatic dictionary download. The only gwaei/win32 issue is random crashes with copy-and-paste when some english letters are added to a line having 3 to 4 romajis/kanjis... Unlikely for most people, maybe. I just paste the next word before deleting the previous one from the buffer.  PS: Wow, you're THE dev for gWaei. Took me a while to notice. Nice to meet you!

Answer (score 1):

You could give [Gozoku](http://int64.org/projects/gozoku) a try.

[image]

Comment: Looks good, thanks. I'll give this a try to get the obligatory Japanese fonts working (missing in XP): http://www.coscom.co.jp/help3/jpfont/jpfont.html

Answer (score 1):

For Windows, you have [JWPce](http://www.physics.ucla.edu/~grosenth/jwpce.html) that does a great job. It doesn't even require the japanese language resources to be installed, and has a very good radical-kanji lookup tool. But the UI is a little bit dated.

Comment: +1! I don't mind old GUI's, being a bit of a version dinosaur myself. Hmm, I thought I closed the question by accepting an answer, but I appreciate options. I will definitely check out the Kanji lookups, because of the riddles involved in creating a Kanji for input (to be translated) when the source is just a piece of paper or a non copy-pastable image.

Answer (score 1):

It's not perfect, but I have gWaei 3.4.0 packaged with an installer for Windows.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/gwaei/files/gwaei/3.4.0/gWaei%203.4.0%20Setup.exe/download

Hopefully when the final gtk-3.4 comes out I can make it use the native theme instead of Adwaita. :)